# accessing links saved in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php   
   include("config.php");    
   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from links WHERE id='2'");    
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))   
   {    
     $data=$row['cnc'];    
     echo "$data";   
   }    
?>
```

So this is my php code to retrieve links saved in my database in "cnc" column of "links" table. I am able to get the links in "$data" variable but what i want to do is to access the value of the variable ,i.e, the link, to proceed to that particular page. What can be done? Can I use "a href" or "header" function to do so.
In short, I want to access links saved in database to get to that particular link. Is it possible to do so.
Help me Please!!!
Thanks...

Comment: Do you want a hyperlink or to be redirected to that URL?

Comment: `header('Location: ' . $row['cnc']);`?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I have tried that @Brad

Comment: @MatthewRiches I want to be redirected to that URL...

Comment: The Link is in $data variable, now how can I access it either as a hyperlink in a href or to be redirected there usind header.

Comment: @SaquibMahfuz You should put what you've tried in your question rather than wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I am not telling anybody to waste their time in order to help...

Comment: @Conrad Lotz Thnaks...

Answer (score 0):

If as you say you want to just be redirect to the URL, you should do this with your code:

```
include("config.php");    
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from links WHERE id='2'");    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
    $data=$row['cnc'];    
    header("Location:".$data);   
}
```

However the mysql commands are deprecated so you should be using something like this (and only get the column you actually want:

```
$sql="SELECT `cnc` FROM `links` WHERE `id` =?";
$sth=$pdo_dbh->prepare($sql);
$data=array($fields);
$sth->execute($data);
$result=$sth->fetchColumn();
header("Location:".$result);
```

The manual for PDO can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php